# Django - when 1 user accesses the same view with different url kwargs - why am I getting cross over of data?

Tags: django

I have a django app that contains samples. On my home page, it displays a table with many samples, containing hyperlinks to the 'Sample page' - which is a view get request.

When I click on several of these samples in tandem, to open new tabs, each to a specific tab - I am getting cross over of data - I.e the url sample_id kwargs is different, but the page is displaying the same results which is incorrect. When i refresh the page, the correct sample data appears.

Is there any way around this happening is a user is to open several different sample tabs at the same time? This would impact on results and could cause errors in the workflow offered by the django app.

*is this because my view is processing too much, so the different view request=s ends up over lapping ?

Edit: adding view:

```
class FilterVariantSampleView(ReportView, ReportPDFGenerator, FileGenerator, limsQuery):

    template_name = os.path.join(
        'results',
        'filter_templates',
        'sample_page.html'
    )

    type = 'sample'
    choice = False
    group_required = ['filter']


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):


        self.user = request.user
        self.obtain_sample_information(kwargs)
        self.obtain_patient_information()
        self.obtain_header()


        # create sample notes form
        sample_notes_form = SampleNotesForm(
            instance=self.sample_obj)
        self.context['sample_notes_form'] = sample_notes_form

        self.create_variant_filter_formset()

        panel_list = [o.run_id.machine_panel_id.panel_id
                      for o in self.all_sr_obj]
        if len(panel_list):
            self.panel_obj = panel_list[0]
            # self.generate_hotspot_form()

        self.assess_fails()


        crs_qs = ClinicallyReportedSample.objects.filter(
            sample_id=self.sample_obj)

        crs_qs = crs_qs.exclude(
            reported_on_panel__parent_panel__isnull=False,
            primary_technical_report=False,
            final_technical_report=False
        )

        remove_report_form_list = []

        lims_molecular_results = self.query_lims_clone_molecular(
            qs=crs_qs)

        mol_df = lims_molecular_results[0]
        summary = lims_molecular_results[1]
        self.context['summary'] = summary
        

        if crs_qs.count() == 1:

            crs_obj = crs_qs[0]
            self.context['crs_qs'] = crs_qs

            remove_report_form = RemoveDiagnosticReportForm(
                instance=crs_obj)
            remove_report_form_list.append(remove_report_form)


        else:
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.WARNING,
                'This sample has been sequenced on multiple panels.')
            self.context['crs_qs'] = crs_qs

            lims_molecular_results = self.query_molecular_lims(
                sample_obj=self.sample_obj)

            for crs_obj in crs_qs:

                remove_report_form = RemoveDiagnosticReportForm(
                    instance=crs_obj)
                remove_report_form_list.append(remove_report_form)

                if crs_obj.diagnostic_report_required == False:
                    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.WARNING,
                        f'This sample does NOT require a diagnostic reoprt '
                        f'for the {crs_obj.reported_on_panel} panel.')

        self.context['remove_report_form_list'] = remove_report_form_list

        return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        """

        self.define_variant_filter_formset()

        submit = request.POST.get('submit', None)


        if submit:

            if submit == 'Modify sample':
                logger.info('')
                logger.info('Sample: {}'.format(self.sample_obj))
                logger.info("Submit: '{}'".format(submit))

                # pass POST dict to formset
                modify_formset = self.CRVFormSet(request.POST, prefix='crv')
                # validate
                if modify_formset.is_valid():
                    logger.info('Modify Variant Formset valid')
                    logger.info('')

                    self.modify_variants(modify_formset)
                    self.modify_sample()

                    return HttpResponseRedirect(
                        reverse('results:filter_variant_sample',
                                kwargs={'sample_id': self.sample_obj.id}))

                else:
                    msg = ('Modify ClinicallyReportedVariant '
                        f'Formset NOT valid: {modify_formset.errors}')
                    logger.error(msg)
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, msg)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(
                        reverse('results:filter_variant_sample',
                                kwargs={'sample_id': self.sample_obj.id}))


            elif submit == 'Update':
                form = RemoveDiagnosticReportForm(request.POST,
                    instance=ClinicallyReportedSample.objects.get(
                        sample_id=kwargs['sample_id'],
                        reported_on_panel=request.POST['reported_on_panel'])
                    )
                if form.is_valid():
                    logger.info('RemoveDiagnosticReportForm is valid')
                    try:
                        form.save()
                    except Exception as e:
                        logger.error(e)
                else:
                    msg = f'RemoveDiagnosticReportForm is NOT valid: {form.errors}'
                    logger.error(msg)
                    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, msg)


                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

            elif 'Download' in submit:

                panel_name = submit.split(' ')[1]
                self.panel_obj = Panel.objects.get(panel_name=panel_name)

                self.crs_obj = ClinicallyReportedSample.objects.get(
                    sample_id=self.sample_obj, reported_on_panel=self.panel_obj)

                if 'panel data' in submit:
                    logger.info(f'Downloading data for {self.sample_obj}')

                    if self.crs_obj.sample_id.external_dept.site in ['Newcastle', 'Sheffield']:
                        downloaded_data = self.download_yne_data()
                        if downloaded_data:
                            self.crs_obj.downloaded_data = True
                            self.crs_obj.downloaded_data_user = request.user
                            self.crs_obj.downloaded_data_date = timezone.now()

                            self.crs_obj.save()
                            return downloaded_data
                        else:
                            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

                elif 'report' in submit:
                    logger.info(f'Downloading report for {self.sample_obj}')

                    # update crs_obj
                    self.crs_obj.download_technical_report = True
                    self.crs_obj.download_technical_report_user = self.user
                    self.crs_obj.download_technical_report_date = timezone.now()
                    self.crs_obj.save()

                    # return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

                    lims_molecular_results = self.query_molecular_lims(
                        sample_obj=self.sample_obj)

                    mol_df = lims_molecular_results[0]
                    summary = lims_molecular_results[1]

                    if mol_df.empty:
                        logger.info('No molecular tests done')
                        self.latex_context['gene_status'] = False

                    else:

                        gene = mol_df[
                            (mol_df['test_name'] == 'gene') &
                            (mol_df['status'] == 'complete')
                        ]

                        if gene.empty:
                            self.context['gene'] = False

                        else:
                            msg = ("gene Sanger in-fill test has been completed.{}")

                            result = gene['result'].to_string(index=False)

                            if result == 'normal or wild-type':
                                msg = msg.format(' No detectable variants.')
                                msg_info = messages.INFO
                                gene_df = pd.DataFrame()
                            elif result == 'failed':
                                msg = msg.format(' Unfortunately the test failed.')
                                msg_info = messages.WARNING
                                gene_df = pd.DataFrame()
                            elif result == 'mutated' or result == 'suspicious':
                                gene_df = self.get_gene_result(gene, technical_report=True)
                                if result == 'suspicious':
                                    msg = msg.format(' There is suspicion of a variant '
                                        '(see below for more information).')
                                else:
                                    msg = msg.format(' A variant was detected '
                                        '(see below for more information).')
                                msg_info = messages.INFO
                            else:
                                msg = msg.format(' Error - contact administrator.')
                                msg_info = messages.ERROR
                                result = 'error'
                                gene_df = pd.DataFrame()

                            self.latex_context['gene_status'] = result
                            self.latex_context['gene_df'] = gene_df

                            logger.info(msg)
                            messages.add_message(self.request, msg_info, msg)



                    print(self.latex_context)

                    # call method from TechnicalReportPDFGenerator
                    self.generateReport(report_type='technical')
                    response = self.download_technical_report()

                    return response

        return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)
```

Comment: Can you add your view to the question?

Comment: sure - have done now

Comment: It's hard to tell as there are a few methods missing but is it possible you have a mutable class attribute that you arewriting to and all instances of the view are reading/writing the same attr?

Comment: I am subclassing this view with other "utility classes" where it grabs the methods. Could it be to do with this? - this only happens when i run this view multiple times in tandem. I.e it never pulls across incorrect data from the previous request if i space them apart by say 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the cache of your browser, are you sure the calls are going through the first time ?

Comment: This happens when I am hosting using NGINX. I would have assumed NGINX could separate the requests, but it still has crossover of data.

Comment: How can i check the calls are going through, what do you mean?

Comment: You can look at the logs of your django app, print the headers and see if the host / referer seem correct